# Will my performance improve if I switch from ASP.NET MVC & WebApi to an index.html and WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that currently uses ASP.NET MVC to just serve the one index.cshtml page. On that page I don't use any Razor code with the exception of bundling (which I am looking to replace with an alternative).

The web page is served by a single controller with a single action with no authentication on that action needed. All the data for the page and the login and registration are performed with WebAPI.

Would there be any advantage in me taking ASP.NET MVC out of the loop and going directly to the index.html page at the root level of my project?

Comment: Be warned - "premature optimisation is the root of all evil..". You'll still be using the ASP.NET pipeline for the Web API calls anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make the biggest difference for the first request before the worker process is warmed up. Users will the HTML markup right away instead of staring at a blank page before all the modules load. But the same approach can be done by having the default application page to be a static HTML file that redirects to an MVC route using the refresh meta tag.

As mentioned, there will be a slight performance advantage otherwise. It is up to you to decide whether it is worth the missing functionality.

Comment: How often will the worker process warm up? Will that be just the very first time that the project is started up on Azure or on each request ?

Comment: It gets recycled at least once a day. It will also get recycled after 30 minutes of inactivity in IIS with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a tiny bit of improvement, as IIS is issuing a static html file from disk, instead of running through the ASP.NET pipeline.

But thats about it.

And we're talking less than 1-5 ms improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It will go faster becouse .NET engine don't need to handle the request. However in this case I think you will not be able to notice the differens.

If you thought about just serving static HTML you maybe want to use a faster webserver or host your static file on a CDN and call "your APIs" thru another URL like.

*www.mydomain.com* <- Static file thru CDN

*api.mydomain.com* <- Used for interaction with the site, all AJAX request goes here and so on